# Should I use generics whenever possible or is object ok in some cases?

Tags: object-oriented, generics

I'm having an interface `ProgressReporter` which basically takes a list of input items (the working queue) through a method `SetWorkPackages(IEnumerable<T> workPackages)` and then has another method `FinishedWorkPackage(T workPackage)` to indicate that one package has been finished.

It will then handle this the correct way, i.e. display a new percentage number, update a progress bar on the UI, whatever is implemented.

Using generics, I have to call it like this:

```
var cpr = new ConsoleProgressReporter<WorkPackage>();
cpr.SetWorkPackages(...);
cpr.FinishedWorkPackage(...);
```

Actually, I have the feeling that the user does not really care about the type `T`, because he never gets results back through the API. Even internally in the current implementations, it does not matter what type `T` is.

Is it ok in such cases, to just allow `object` instead of using generics? Are there general guidelines when to use generics and when to use `object`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it makes no difference whatsoever what the element type is, then sure, you could ignore the fact that they're `T` objects. But if you're never going to perform any `T`-specific operations on them, why store the objects at all? You might be better off with just a counter recording how many they are.

The only situation where I can imaging holding things as `Object`s makes sense is if you want to call `Object`-defined methods but not `T`-defined methods in them, e.g. `toString()`. But frankly, there aren't all that many useful `Object` methods to begin with.

Comment: Actually one thing I'm currently doing is call `.ToString()` in the ConsoleProgressReporter. But that's more "using what is there", I would not need it desperately. The more important advantage I saw in saving the object (the hash would also be ok) was to double check internally, if `FinishedWorkPackage()` was called two times for the same object.

Comment: @Aufziehvogel small side note - the hash is not normally *completely* unique

Comment: @AlexFoxGill But `equals()` should be. I think enforcing uniqueness via equals (or equivalently, storing things in a `Set`) would be a valid reason to retain the items as `Object`s.